# How to make rosbuild package depend on catkin package?

Tags: ros, catkin, overlay, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my rosbuild package I have a dependency one of my catkin packages:

```
<depend package="myCatkinPackage"/>
```

Calling *rosmake myRosbuildPackage* generates an error since the catkin package was not found. I can roscd to both catkin and rosbuild packages. I tried overlaying my rosbuild ws on top of my catkin ws:

```
$ cd ~/path/to/rosbuild_ws
$ rosws init . ~/path/to/catkin_ws/devel
$ source setup.sh
```

Now it does not find any rosbuild packages (only the catkin_ws is in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH).
What is the correct way of depending on catkin packages from rosbuild?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105231/how-to-make-rosbuild-package-depend-on-catkin-package?/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out a way to get it to work without involving rosws and setupfiles. I just added the following line to bashrc:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:~/path/to/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig
```

---

Originally posted by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) with karma: 328 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-27**:
This looks like a hack. The principle of what you were trying is correct: Overlay the catkin_ws from the rosbuild one.

**Comment by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on 2013-11-27**:
This is basically what setup.sh does (but it does not add it to bashrc of course). On top of that, the setup file also changes ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to point only on catkin_ws (but not rosbuild_ws), which is kind of counterproductive. The best thing with my solution is that it works ;-)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-27**:
It just seems to me that setup.sh should do everything you need (e.g. correct ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) and if it doesn't the setup is somewhat wrong, which might get you into trouble later.